# python asyncioモジュールを用いたtcp clientの書き方について

Tags: python, python3, tcp, 非同期

asyncioを用いてtcp clientを作成しています。
ネットで以下のようなコードを拾ったのですが、
これを1回だけの実行ではなく、ずっと(loop.run_forever?)回すには
どう書いたら良いでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

```py
import asyncio


async def tcp_echo_client(message, loop):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 8888,
                                                   loop=loop)

    print('Send: %r' % message)
    writer.write(message.encode())

    data = await reader.read(100)
    print('Received: %r' % data.decode())

    print('Close the socket')
    writer.close()


message = 'Hello World!'
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(tcp_echo_client(message, loop))
loop.close()
```

Comment: 例えばこの記事とか参考になるのでは？ [Python simple socket client/server using asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48506460/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます！助かります。